# Can I use my Windows partition as Virtualbox machine?

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu and Windows in dualboot. Can I use my ntfs Windows system partition as my Virtualbox machine? When I install an app in VB to have it installed in my 'real' Win system.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is No, but I have never tried so now I am curious too...

Answer (score 3):

The drastic hardware differences between the physical and virtual machine will almost certainly cause Windows to choke. Windows is not entirely friendly towards the entire hardware platform changing between reboots. Usually to do so you would need to "[generalise](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation)" the operating system so that it knows

Windows [can not be moved to another PC (VM to Real Machine or vice versa) without being generalised](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview).

> #### Unsupported Scenarios
>
> The following scenarios are not supported:
>
> - Moving or copying a Windows image to a different PC without generalizing the PC is not supported

You are also limited to generalising a particular operating system "image" [8 times](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation):

> #### Limits on how many times you can run Sysprep
>
> You can run the Sysprep command up to 8 times on a single Windows image.

Constantly changing the hardware may cause the OS to need to re-authenticate it's licence and potentially cause your copy of Windows to mark itself as "non-genuine".

If you want it in a VM then put it in its own partition or virtual disk for the purpose.

Comment: While generally true, there are quite few articles about this procedure, how to achieve shared Windows in dualboot and VB. It can be done and was used. I asume it depends a lot on the mother board features like AMD-V to share the HW in a sofisticated way. What is unclear to me is the real long-term experience, whether users over *months* or *years* do get crashes and data loses. For users with following scenario - who need to run only two programs (and they can't be "wined" and one, less used can't run on VM) - it is worth to do a little research.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 If you can describe the process necessary to achieve it and have any experience of it then it seems to me that would make a good answer. I have only given information that I have found based on my knowledge that Windows "locks" to the system hardware and that the hardware would be distinctly different between a Windows OS the "full" OS and it running as a guest. Having something to the contrary, especially with a "how to" and what problems might occur would be a good thing. It might even be what OP is looking for, more so than my "probably not" answer.

Comment: I understand your answer and I do think it is perfectly valid from the formal point of view. I just felt a comment that it can be done can be useful to readers. I found and read about 3 howtos so far, but they are all from fresh users. Even how to clone HW keys into the VM, so that you run "same" HW and only need 1licence. However, I feel a long-term proof & experience is desirable before testing. I will be adding a new box in few weeks and this solution looks super-ineresting, worth a research I'doing.